# COUNTIFS to count text values in a column

Tags: excel

I am using the below SUMIFS function to count the total numbers in a column where the value in another column (column c) matches that in cell C7:

```
=SUMIFS('Time Allocation'!$C$505:$C$10001,'Time Allocation'!$B$505:$B$10001, "="&$C7)
```

Now I want to do exactly the same kind of thing but this time I want to count the number of times there is a text value of any kind in a column where the value in column c matches that in cell C7.

Because sum only works for numbers and I want to count the cells with text values, I have tried using:

```
=COUNTIFS('Time Allocation'!$C$505:$C$10001,'Time Allocation'!$B$505:$B$10001, "="&$C7)
```

But this says not enough arguments in my formula.

Please can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Your formulas suggest that you are in fact matching the value in C7 within column B, not column C as you indicate. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this.

```
=sumproduct((('Time Allocation'!$C$505:$C$10001)=('Timeallocation'!$B$505:$B$10001))*(ISNUMBER(('Time Allocation'!$B$505:$B$10001))=FALSE))
```

I may have missed a parenthesis or two, its supposed to be

```
sumproduct(((C:C)=(B:B))*(isnumber(C:C)=FALSE))
```

just hard to check for errors with long column names. This should be the sum of a set of 0's and 1's that are 1 when there is not and number and they are equal.